Opcache reset getting called automatically as per Dynatrace
I've a simple shell script which echoes opcache_reset in a PHP file and calls it via curl to flush the opcache of Apache Web Server. This works perfectly fine and can be verified in the output of opcache_get_status as well (last_restart_time parameter).
However, our monitoring tool Dynatrace reports the Opcache manual resets happening every minute. This is not reflected in the output of opcache_get_status which still shows the time when my script was manually called, which is correct.
Dynatrace stops reporting the manual resets when I manually restart the Apache Web Service, so its not totally crazy for sure.
My Opcache configs as below
opcache.memory_consumption=256
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=64
opcache.max_accelerated_files=10000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.validate_timestamps=0

Attached is the screengrab from Dynatrace
